# set 7pm on first field and show 7:30 in second field with previous time disabled

Tags: php

```
$('#OutletEvents_start_time').datetimepicker({
        datepicker:false,
        format: 'h:i a',
        step:30,

        onSelectTime: function(){

        $('#OutletEvents_end_time').val();

        }
    });
```

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thank you